# How do I run my Winzip command line statement from within PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a WinZip command line statement I'd like to run from within PowerShell. How do I run this? It works fine when I run from the command line.

```
$expression = `"c:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\WZZIP.EXE`" -a -P -r `"c:\temp\test.zip`" `"\\...\*.*`"

Invoke-Expression `"$expression`"
```

Thanks!

Update - Included full command line statement I'm trying to use. Do I need to escape any of the characters?

Update 2 - the value of $expression is the correct path however the Invoke-Expression still throws the "'x86' is not recognized..." error.

```
 $expression = ${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + '\WinZip\WZZIP.EXE -a -P -r c:\temp\test.zip \\...\*.*'
```

Comment: What error do you get when you attempt to do this in PowerShell?

Comment: Currently getting this error... "x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again."

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace("c:\temp\testfolder")
$zipPackage.CopyHere(c:\temp\test.zip)
```

This [link](http://blogs.inetium.com/blogs/mhodnick/archive/2006/08/07/295.aspx) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$expression = "c:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\WZZIP.EXE"

& $expression -a -P -r "c:\temp\test.zip" "\\...\*.*"
```

should work