# How do I use a UNC path in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell code that calls WinZip and makes an archive.

```
$program = "c:\program files (x86)\WinZip\WZZIP.EXE"

& $program -a -P -r c:\temp\test.zip ("\\server.domain.com\FirstName LastName\ProjectId\*.*")
```

The two backslashes are part of a UNC path. I must use UNC and a fully qualified domain name.

The above code attempts to run but hangs until I kill it (press the stop button in ISE).

When I wrap the UNC path in parenthesis, again the code attempts to run but hangs.

How do I fix this? I'm stuck with UNC paths and using WinZip.

Comment: If the code is hanging, it's most likely a problem with WinZip. Why are you forced to use WinZip? I would strongly recommend using 7-Zip instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run my Winzip command line statement from within PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407270/how-do-i-run-my-winzip-command-line-statement-from-within-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

UNC paths are not supported in WinZip from the command line. You will need to map a drive letter to the UNC path before preforming the zip. You can easily script this:

```
net use s: "\\server.domain.com\FirstName LastName\ProjectId\"
```

Alternatively, you can copy the files locally, zip them, then delete them from the local copy leaving only your zip file.

I believe 7zip does not have this limitation and is generally capable of doing everything WinZip is and more.

Comment: I'm not sure if "not supported" means "not *officially* supported, but it may work for you" or it *will not* work but I'm currently running the above command from a command line and the archive is being built just fine. I'm using WinZip 15.5 Pro (9468) with Winzip Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 32-bit (Build 10562)

Comment: It means everything I have found in researching this problem indicates it is not supported. Furthermore, there is no mention of support from WinZip: http://kb.winzip.com/kb/search/?s=1&q=unc&sb=Go

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to your question, perhaps you could use the PowerShell module PowerShellZIP at CodePlex (http://powershellzip.codeplex.com/) to create the ZIP files for you.

Then you can use the full powershell pipeline to create the ZIP files rather than calling out to WinZip.

I haven't tested to see if this module can zip files from an UNC path tho..